# Stop multiple maven build in cmd

Tags: java, maven, cmd

I've got following

.bat file :

`cd project1 && mvn clean install && cd project2 && mvn clean install`

When project 1 failes on some module, it continue with building project2.

The problem here is that project 2 depends on project 1 and if there is *failure*, I want it to stop.

Do you have any suggestions how can I do that?

Comment: I've used call command but that doesn't helps :/

Comment: First why not using a multi module build...Furthermore if the first fails you should check the return code of the mvn call..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with parent pom with these two projects as modules and run mvn clean install on parent. When there will be a failure building of other projects will be skipped.